# Any way to encrypt persistence.xml for standalone application?

Tags: java, jpa

I do not need a big framework like Glasfish. I have set up a stand alone application with JPA. That means the client will have all the files, include the persistence.xml.

Any way to encrypt that? I do not want to give away the mysql credentials.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're giving software and configuration data to another party, for them to run in their environment.  Since they control that environment, there is no reason to think that you can keep anything about what you're providing confidential.  In particular, if you had a way to encrypt `persistence.xml`, it likely would be of little use against any decent hacker, because your program needs to *de*crypt the contents before they can be used.

I suppose you're most concerned about the database access credentials, and therefore that your application connects to a central DB managed by you.  If you don't have at least a moderate level of trust for your users then this is a rather questionable plan.

Nevertheless, if you proceed this way then I would suggest creating separate database credentials for each user to whom you grant access, and locking down the access granted to these users as much as possible.  Using a database that affords fine-grained access control may help here.  You should also consider keeping an audit trail / transaction log sufficient to detect and correct any damage a user may do (whether through trying to hack you or because of a bug in the software).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot encrypt the persistence.xml.
But instead of putting the properties in the persistence.xml you can pass a Map when creating the EntityManger

```
EntityManager createEntityManager(SynchronizationType synchronizationType, Map map)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#createEntityManager-javax.persistence.SynchronizationType-java.util.Map-

So you are able to have the properties encrypted in another file. But you will need the decrypt the credentials and the all what John said will apply.